# Python Game: Craps

Tags: python-3.x

```
def c():
dice = r.randint(1,6)
dice2 = r.randint(1,6)
craps = 2, 3, 12
natural = 7, 11
count = 0
return (dice,dice2,craps,natural,count)

for i in range(1,10000+1):
    result = c()
    dice = result[0]
    dice2 = result[1]
    craps = result[2]
    natural = result[3]
    count = result[4]
    while (dice+dice2)!= natural or (dice+dice2) != craps:
            c()
            count+=1
print("You won", count,"games!")
```

I want it to play the game craps 10,000 times and print the games won, but everything I do ends with dice or count not being defined, I've tried everything for several hours, so I thought I'd ask for some help here.

EDIT: I fixed return, and functions, but now it simply won't print anything. Suggestions? Code has been edited to show what I changed

Comment: You try to return four values, but never assign any of them. Also you can only `return` once: the next three lines are never reached. And you try to add one to `count` before actually defining it.

Comment: Function `c` will return `dice` and then come to an end. It will never execute the other `return` statements. But there are other errors.

Comment: You probably want to call `c` first in your loop and check its results.

Comment: What do you mean when you say check its results Mr. Bell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def c():
dice = r.randint(1,6)  # this is limited to c() function
dice2 = r.randint(1,6) # this is limited to c() function
craps = 2, 3, 12       # this is limited to c() function
natural = 7, 11        # this is limited to c() function
return dice            # this value will return
return dice2           # this value is skipped
return craps           # this value is skipped
return natural         # this value is skipped

for i in range(1,10000+1):
    while (dice+dice2)!= natural or (dice+dice2) != craps:
            count += 1
            c()
print("You won", count,"games!")
```

The value dice1, dice2, natural and craps are not working in the for loop because their scope is limited to the c() function.

you can return all the values using tulp

```
def c():
    dice = r.randint(1,6)  
    dice2 = r.randint(1,6) 
    craps = 2, 3, 12       
    natural = 7, 11        
    return (dice,dice2,craps,natural)
```

to get the value you will have to do this.

```
for i in range(1,10000+1):
    result = c()
    dice = result[0]
    dice2 = result[1]
    craps = result[2]
    natural = result[3]
...
```

Comment: Ya I tried returning just one value, and (forgive me I can't exactly remember) all it did was either not print "You won" count "games" it simply printed nothing, or it still said it was undefined

Comment: So I added what you suggested, and it didn't give errors but it didn't print anything. Got any other ideas?

Comment: what is your goal. when is it suppose to print "You won The games!"

Comment: I want it to print "You won", count, "Games" because inside the while loop it is counting every game that is won.